# Compare Tables and write the difference results to a file/table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have two tables with the same schema/structure.  Both the tables can have data which is not present in another.
I need to find the differences between them and put the result into a file.
ID column is the key but can have multiple entries.

> The results should be like in Difference table **where an exact match of row from Table A in Table B or row from Table B in Table A should be ignored and all others should be captured**.

I thought of using **COALESCE** and then doing a comparison.
Sample tables below, is there a better and faster way to do this when the column count is more(10 columns)?

[image: Tables Below:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it can be solved using `MINUS` set operator + `UNION ALL`:

```
(select * from t1 
minus
select * from t2)

UNION ALL 

(select * from t2
minus
select * from t1)
```

But the problem is Hive does not support MINUS or EXCEPT operators.

You can use left joins to get records which do not match in one table and UNION ALL with records which do not match in another table.

```
select * from
(
select a.id, a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, 'table_a' as src 
      from table_a 
           left join table_b 
                  on a.id=b.id 
                 and a.col1=b.col1 
                 and a.col2=b.col2 
                 and a.col3=b.col3
  where b.id is null --not matching in table_b

  UNION ALL --You may want to use UNION instead of UNION All to remove duplicates

select b.id, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3, 'table_b' as src 
  from table_b 
       left join table_a 
              on a.id=b.id 
             and a.col1=b.col1 
             and a.col2=b.col2 
             and a.col3=b.col3
 where a.id is null --not matching in table_a
 ) s
 order by id, src; --order to put similar records together
```

I added `src` column, so you can easily identify to which table the record belongs, you can remove it if not necessary.

The same can be done using correlated NOT EXISTS instead of LEFT JOIN, but it produces exactly the same plan in Hive, no difference in performance.

Also if your table can contain NULLs and you want to match them also,
use `NVL()` function in join `ON` condition, for example like this:

`NVL(a.col3, 'NULL')=NVL(b.col3,'NULL')` --for numeric columns use some constant like `-999999` instead of `'NULL'`.

Comment: I changed the question to be more precise and col2 can be different too...

Comment: @user1529282 Proposed another solution